# Displaying user selected custom tags/taxonomies on the front-end

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags, profiles

I would be grateful if anybody could point me in the right direction please.

I have a WordPress setup which utilises [Theme My Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/) and https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-tags/, to allow users "tag" their user profiles from the front-end.

This works great but I am having difficulty displaying the user's selected tags when somebody is viewing their public/front-end profile.

I have the following code, which simply lists all the tags available - however I am unsure of how to alter this code so that it only lists the tags that the specific user has specified;

```
<?php 
     $args = array('taxonomy' => 'user_sector' );
     $categories = get_categories($args);

     foreach($categories as $category) { 
        echo '<div class="sector">'. $category->name.'</div>';
     } 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody needs to do this too - I was able to achieve this with the following code;

```
<?php
     $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $userid, 'user_sector' );

     foreach($terms as $term) {
         echo '<div class="sector">'. $term->name.'</div>';
     }
?>
```

Comment: You can add a feature request in here https://github.com/UmeshSingla/user-tags ;)